# NSIS 2.46 Reading registry: "." in subkey lets ReadRegStr fail

Tags: registry, nsis

I have a problem with the command `ReadRegStr`, using `2016.`" in the subkey as seen below:

```
ReadRegStr 
   $INSTDIR2016_5x64 
   "HKLM"
   "SOFTWARE\Autodesk\Maya\2016.5\Setup\InstallPath" "MAYA_INSTALL_LOCATION"
```

It works fine without the `.`, so it works for Maya 2016. ;)

So the `.` seems to be the problem.

Anybody any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS does not parse the registry path, it is passed directly to the Windows registry functions:

```
Section
# Write example value
WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\NSIS\Test\Maya\2016.5\Setup\InstallPath" "MAYA_INSTALL_LOCATION" "c:\foo\bar"
# Read it
ReadRegStr $0 HKCU "SOFTWARE\NSIS\Test\Maya\2016.5\Setup\InstallPath" "MAYA_INSTALL_LOCATION"
DetailPrint MAYA_INSTALL_LOCATION=$0
# Clean up
DeleteRegKey HKCU "SOFTWARE\NSIS\Test"
SectionEnd
```

It is possible that you are seeing a 64-bit vs 32-bit registry issue or registry virtualization/redirection. Download [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to verify that you are accessing the correct key...